# Calculate 2 sets of input types using javascript in one html page

Tags: javascript, html, function

I have 2 set of input types of text boxes. 2 fields on each. I am trying to calculate and compare each set individually in single page.
The input types have different ids.

```
<input type="text" id="tmcp_textfield_1" name="blueberry" 
placeholder="blueberry" value="0" onkeydown="calculate()" 
onkeyup="calculate()">
<input type="text" id="tmcp_textfield_2" name="plums" placeholder="plums" value="0" 
onkeydown="calculate()" onkeyup="calculate()">
<input type="text" id="a3" name="a3" placeholder="a3" value="0">

<br>second set below<br>
<input type="text" id="tmcp_textfield_3" name="blueberry" 
placeholder="blueberry" value="0" onkeydown="calculate()" 
onkeyup="calculate()">
<input type="text" id="tmcp_textfield_4" name="plums" placeholder="plums" value="0" 
onkeydown="calculate()" onkeyup="calculate()">
<input type="text" id="a3`" name="a3" placeholder="a3" value="0">
```

My javascript in header:
For First set:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    calculate = function() {
        var blueb = parseFloat($('#tmcp_textfield_1').val());//document.getElementById('blueberry').value;
        var plumsb = parseFloat($('#tmcp_textfield_2').val());//document.getElementById('plums').value; 
        var thetotal = /*document.getElementById('a3').value =*/ parseInt(blueb)+parseInt(plumsb);
        if (thetotal > 6) {
            $('#tmcp_textfield_2').val('');
            $('#tmcp_textfield_1').val('');
            alert('Combination must be below 6');
        }
    }
</script>
```

For Second Set:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    calculate = function() {
        var blueb = parseFloat($('#tmcp_textfield_3').val());//document.getElementById('blueberry').value;
        var plumsb = parseFloat($('#tmcp_textfield_4').val());//document.getElementById('plums').value; 
        var thetotal = /*document.getElementById('a3').value =*/ parseInt(blueb)+parseInt(plumsb);

        if (thetotal > 12){
            $('#tmcp_textfield_4').val('');
            $('#tmcp_textfield_3').val('');
            alert('Combination must be below 12');
        }
    }
</script>
```

The problem only the first set of calculation work. When i remove the first set of javascript then the second set only work and vise versa.
How could i differentiate the sets in javascript so that both the set of inputs work together in one single html page.

Comment: You can't have two different functions with the same name. Change the names as calculate1 and calculate2 or some other meaningful names.

Comment: Also it would probably be useful to use `var`, `let` or `const` in front of `calculate` so that you don't bind it to the window object.

Comment: Can you distinguish them which functions have the same name under the same scope?

Comment: yes that works cool...but i intend to make the input fields dynamic using php further so doing that i may not have 2 different function names under 1 input field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:** 
You are having same name functions "calculate()" for both sets that's why only 1 is working at a time.

**Solution:**
Rename the function name to different names like `calculateOne()` and `calculateTwo()` then both will work.

Hope this helps

Comment: yes that worked great...but i intend to make the input fields dynamic using php further so doing that i may not have 2 different function names under 1 input field

Comment: you can send parameters in the function for calculating the values of the required field.